# Databricks dbutils.fs.cp

Tags: azure, copy, azure-databricks, dbutils

I am using dbutils.fs.cp(sourcefilepath,destinationfilepath) query to copy a file from one location to another from the azure storages.My source file path is /mnt/testing/StudentA/Test.csv and destination file path is /mnt/Testing_1/. in this case the dbutils is running but in the destination it creates a file with a folder name(StudentA) also it creates a folder called StudentA and place the Test.csv.

Comment: I tried with your code, but could not reproduce the issue. Databricks will only copy the file. The only way it will copy the folder is if you omit the file name like that sourcefilepath="/mnt/testing" . then it will recursively copy all the folder structures under testing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @[Chen Hirsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21079004/chen-hirsh).

```
sourcefilepath="/mnt/testing/StudentA/mycsv2.csv"
destinationfilepath="/mnt/testing1"

dbutils.fs.cp(sourcefilepath,destinationfilepath)
```

This code won't copy the folder, it will only create a new `mycsv2.csv` file in the target location.

The folders copy as mentioned in your question will be copied like below only when you use recursive `True` in the code.

[image]

```
sourcefilepath="/mnt/testing"
destinationfilepath="/mnt/testing1/samp1/"

dbutils.fs.cp(sourcefilepath,destinationfilepath,True)
```

So, recheck your code and file paths. If you don't have any usage with source files, you can also try [`dbutils.fs.mv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils#--mv-command-dbutilsfsmv) as a workaround.